# Jaccard score/distance or percentage overlap

Tags: c#, sql, performance, distance, overlap

I want to be able to calculate the Jaccard score/distance (distance is 1-score) of one rectangle against a grid of rectangles.  My grid is 50x50 (1625625 total rectangles).

I am able to calculate the score of my input rectangle against all of these in .34 seconds, but it's not fast enough as I either need to be able to process 10k rectangles, or store the result in the DB (updating 10s of thousands of rows each call).  So I was hoping to get the DB to do the calculation for me and not have to pull anything out of the DB, however I can't think of how to do this without cursors...

`sourceRectangles` contains my single rectangle (although in reality there will be 10k), `rectangles` contains my grid and `temporaryRectangleList` contains the sum of the scores.

```
Dictionary<UInt32, Rectangle> temporaryRectangleList = new Dictionary<UInt32, Rectangle>();
foreach (var sourceRectangle in sourceRectangles)
{
    foreach (var rectangle in rectangles)
    {
        // For each rectangle within the group
        //foreach (var rectangle in group)
        //{
        int max_MinX = Math.Max(sourceRectangle.MinX, rectangle.MinX);
        int min_MaxX = Math.Min(sourceRectangle.MaxX, rectangle.MaxX);

        // There is an overlap
        //if (max_MinX < min_MaxX)
        //{
        int max_MinY = Math.Max(sourceRectangle.MinY, rectangle.MinY);
        int min_MaxY = Math.Min(sourceRectangle.MaxY, rectangle.MaxY);


        // Calculate the area of the overlap
        int area = ((min_MaxX - max_MinX)*(min_MaxY - max_MinY));
        // Store the Jaccard score
        var score = (double) area/((sourceRectangle.Area + rectangle.Area) - area);

        if (temporaryRectangleList.ContainsKey(rectangle.ID))
        {
            temporaryRectangleList[rectangle.ID].Weight += score;
        }
        else
        {
            temporaryRectangleList.Add(rectangle.ID, new Rectangle(rectangle, score));
        }
    }
}
```

I need to be able to lookup the items in the dictionary as I need to pull data out of it via the ID of the rectangle.

If you think you can speed up the C# to be faster (10k rectangles process <1s) then go for it, but .34s is the best I can do per rectangle, so I'm looking for a SQL equivalent of this code (ideally better though... lol).

Unfortunately, the SQL table is too large to dump here, so I can only give you the structure:

```
USE [Rectangles]
GO

/****** Object:  Table [dbo].[PreProcessed]    Script Date: 14/01/2014 16:39:33 ******/
SET ANSI_NULLS ON
GO

SET QUOTED_IDENTIFIER ON
GO

CREATE TABLE [dbo].[PreProcessed](
    [ID] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MinX] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MinY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MaxX] [int] NOT NULL,
    [MaxY] [int] NOT NULL,
    [Area] [int] NOT NULL,
 CONSTRAINT [PK_PreProcessed] PRIMARY KEY CLUSTERED 
(
    [ID] ASC,
    [Area] ASC
)WITH (PAD_INDEX = OFF, STATISTICS_NORECOMPUTE = OFF, IGNORE_DUP_KEY = OFF, ALLOW_ROW_LOCKS = ON, ALLOW_PAGE_LOCKS = ON) ON [PRIMARY]
) ON [PRIMARY]

GO
```

Rectangle Class:

```
public class Rectangle
{
    public Rectangle(UInt32 id, int minX, int maxX, int minY, int maxY, double weight)
    {
        ID = id;
        MinX = minX;
        MaxX = maxX;
        MinY = minY;
        MaxY = maxY;
        Area = (maxX - minX)*(maxY - minY);
        Weight = weight;
    }

    public Rectangle(Rectangle input, double weight)
    {
        ID = input.ID;
        MinX = input.MinX;
        MaxX = input.MaxX;
        MinY = input.MinY;
        MaxY = input.MaxY;
        Area = input.Area;
        Weight = weight;
    }

    public int Area { get; set; }
    public int MinX { get; set; }
    public int MaxX { get; set; }
    public int MinY { get; set; }
    public int MaxY { get; set; }

    public UInt32 ID { get; set; }
    public double Weight { get; set; }
}
```

Comment: If you can switch the inner and the outerloop you can get rid off the dictionarylookup and you can inline the Math.Max and Math.Min. In my small test I got the best benefit by changing the Retangle from a class to a struct (and making the members fields instead of properties).

Answer (score 0):

SQL Server has the `geometry` data type.  This has methods for calculating the intersection and union of polygons.